# Add All Values in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I don't know how to calculate the quantity in a loop.

```
 <tr v-for="product in products">
        <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
        <td>
            <span v-for="price in product.prices" v-html=" '&#8369; ' + price.price + ', '"></span>
         </td>
       <td >
           <span v-for="quantity in product.quantities">{{ Need to total quantities here. }}</span>
       </td>
  </tr>
```

My Data

[image]

I need to total all quantities. I highlighted the qty. TY

Comment: Use a computed property which returns `product.quantities.reduce((sum, product) => sum + product.qty, 0)`. You could also create a filter. See http://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: Thanks, I'm still figuring out your solution.

Comment: It doesn't work. I think your .reduce will work if the data is look like this. `donutData: [
        { label: 'Openstaande verzoeken', value: 20 },
        { label: 'Geaccepteerde verzoeken', value: 25 },
        { label: 'Afgewezen verzoeken', value: 10 }
    ],` My solution is really stupid. I'll post it here. I hope someone can refine the code. Sigh....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some variants.

**1st**

You can add fields to your products array when you get it
script

```
this.products = someData;
this.products.forEach((pr) => {
   pr.totalQuantities = pr.quantities.map((q)=>q.qty).reduce(function(total, q) {
                 return total + q}, 0);
})
```

template

```
<tr v-for="product in products">
        <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
        <td>
            <span v-for="price in product.prices" v-html=" '&#8369; ' + 
              price.price + ', '"></span>
         </td>
       <td >
           <span>{{product.totalQuantities}}</span>
       </td>
  </tr>
```

**2nd**

Add filter to count total
script (insert into vue instance)

```
filters: {
    total: function (quantities) {
      return quantities.map((q)=>q.qty).reduce(function(total, q) {
                 return total + q}, 0);
    }
  }
```

template

```
<tr v-for="product in products">
        <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
        <td>
            <span v-for="price in product.prices" v-html=" '&#8369; ' + 
              price.price + ', '"></span>
         </td>
       <td >
           <span>{{product.quantities | total}}</span>
       </td>
  </tr>
```

**3rd**

script

```
computed: {
   quantities(){
       return products.map(function(pr){
            return pr.quantities.map((q)=>q.qty).reduce(function(total, q) {
                 return total + q}, 0);
       });
   }
}
```

template

```
<tr v-for="product, index in products">
        <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
        <td>
            <span v-for="price in product.prices" v-html=" '&#8369; ' + 
             price.price + ', '"></span>
         </td>
       <td >
           <span>{{ quantities[index] }}</span>
       </td>
  </tr>
```

**variant for work with index**

script

```
   quantities(){
       return (index) => {
          return this.$store.getters.products[index].quantities.map((q)=>q.qt‌​y).reduce(function(t‌​otal, q) { return total + q}, 0) }
       }
   }
```

template

```
{{quantities(index)}}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this one and get back on your answers

Comment: There is an error `TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value` I don't know why. The 1st and the 2nd has the same errors.

Comment: I have tried your example and it's working. I'll try this with my real data and get back here. Thanks

Comment: It works now... I need to put it in methods because I need to pass an index. `quantities: function(index){
      return this.$store.getters.products[index].quantities.map((q)=>q.qty).reduce(function(total, q) {
                 return total + q}, 0)
    }` @Kirill Matrosov. Thank you so much...

Comment: @Rbex, it is bad idea to put it to method. it willl recount every instance update. U can use computed property and return function in it. Update post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144645/discussion-between-kirill-matrosov-and-rbex).

Comment: tried your first method, works like charm. Thank You!